# biblatex: weird output

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

My biblatex gives weird output: for example, it writes "[Whi]" instead of ["Whittle"].

Furthermore, I would like to avoid writing the bibliography in the preamble, since the final work includes dozens of citations.

Minimal "working" example:

.tex file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage[
   backend=biber,
   style=alphabetic,
   sorting=ynt
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\title{The definitive research}
\author{The Supreme Chemist}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cite{whittle}

\medskip

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

.bib file

```
@misc{whittle,
    author = "Whittle",
    title  = "Processes and apparatus for extraction of 
              active substances and enriched extracts 
              from natural products."
}
```

[image]

Comment: `biblatex`'s `alphabetic` style is configured to generate a label consisting of the first three letters of the family name of the author (if there is only one author) or the first letter of the family name (if there are more than two authors) plus the last two digits of the year. In your case that gives "Whi". Can you explain the rule you'd like `biblatex` to implement instead?

Comment: I really don't understand your second point, but since each question should only be about one issue anyway (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864), I suggest you ask it in a new question and explain it there in more detail.

Comment: @moewe I'd like to write [Whittle] instead of the just three characters [Whi].

Comment: what do you want it to do for 2 or more authors?

Comment: What's the general rule here, though? What do you want to happen to a paper written by "Sigfridsson and Ryde"? What about a paper by "Aksın, Türkmen, Artok, Çetinkaya, Ni, Büyükgüngör and Özkal"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle an output like [Romano and Radoiu]

Comment: @moewe I'm brand new with BibTex, so thanks for the patience

Comment: and how do you want the bib list styled with such long cite keys, with a very wide label column, or with the entries not aligned or... ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the best solution would be to use an identification number for the citation. For example, [1] for "Perrotin-Brunel, H., Kroon, M. C., Van Roosmalen, M. J., Van Spronsen, J.,"
Peters, C. J., and Witkamp".
This leaves the problem of assigning the corresponding number to each citation

Comment: @user3713179 note you are not using bibtex but biblatex/biber (a style for bibtex would be very different answer than a style for biblatex)

Comment: `style=numeric,` and you're done.

Comment: Numbers are the default but you asked for style=alphabetic, !!!

Comment: ! Package biblatex Error: Style 'number' not found

Comment: Sorry, typo: Should have been `style=numeric,`. Fixed in the original comment.

Comment: Since you're new to `biblatex` you may want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864 to learn more about what it is and how it works.

Comment: Note that `sorting=ynt,` is less commonly used in numeric styles, but since the labels are the only way for people to identify citations by, that does not necessarily make it worse than `sorting=nyt,` (the default). People often use `sorting=none,` with `style=numeric,` so that the citations are numbered "chronologically" by appearance.